# Unable to perform a simple multiplication in script

Tags: sed, awk, scripting, solaris, ksh

I am havingf trouble performing a simple multiplication in my script.

```
while read A B C
do
  tmp=$A\*$C/100 
  echo $tmp >> out1.txt
done < foo.txt
```

foo.txt:

```
13721725        99      100
400198848       170     180
217845440       113     120`
```

Desired out1.txt:

```
value1
value2
value3
```

This is what i my current output is:

```
13721725*100/100
400198848*180/100
217845440*120/100
```

I tried all sorts of combinations

```
tmp=$({A} \* {C/100})
tmp=$($A\*($C/100))
tmp=`$A\*$C/100` (tried to store it using back ticks)
tmp=expr $A\*$C/100
```

Nothing seem to work, i am using KSH and Solaris 5.10.
Any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

awk

```
$ awk '{print $1*$3/100}' file
13721725
7.20358e+08
261414528
```

Assuming you don't want the "scientific" notation:

```
$ awk '{printf "%.1f\n", $1*$3/100}' file
13721725.0
720357926.4
261414528.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this with ksh:

```
while read A B C; do
  tmp=$(($A*$C/100))
  echo $tmp
done < foo.txt > out1.txt
```

Output to out1.txt:

```
13721725
720357926
261414528
```

See: [Performing arithmetic on variables in the Korn shell](http://osr507doc.sco.com/en/OSUserG/_math_on_var_in_ksh.html)

Comment: It worked, thank you. But i liked glenns answer as it avoids the need of loop. Thanks though for providing right syntax.